# SUM of filtered attributes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have got this XML

```
<food>
  <foodprice foodID="1" Price="10.0000"></foodprice>
  <foodprice foodID="2" Price="20.0000"></foodprice>
  <foodprice foodID="3" Price="30.0000"></foodprice>
</food>
<basket Name="Any1">
  <vegetables foodID="1"></vegetables>
  <vegetables foodID="2"></vegetables>
</basket>
<basket Name="Any2">
  <vegetables foodID="1"></vegetables>
</basket>
<basket Name="Any3">
  <vegetables foodID="1"></vegetables>
  <vegetables foodID="3"></vegetables>
</basket>
<basket Name="Any4">
  <vegetables foodID="2"></vegetables>
  <vegetables foodID="3"></vegetables>
</basket>
```

Now, I selected values for each basket used variable and filter

```
<xsl:template match="vegetables">
    <xsl:variable name="vegId" select="@foodID"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/food/foodprice[@foodID=$vegId]">
        <xsl:value-of select="(/ROOT/food/foodprice[@foodID=$vegId]/@Price div count(/ROOT/Basket/vegetables[@foodID=$vegId]))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is -

```
Any1
3,33
10

Any2
3,33

Any3
3,33
15

Any4
10
15
```

My question is, how can I calculate the sum of `Any1 13,33; Any2 3,33; Any3 18,33; Any4 25` etc.

thanks

Comment: your code not make proper understand please post that template where you are printing Any1 3,33 10 etc...

Comment: printable template is for example: <xsl:template name="anytemplate">; <xsl:apply-templates select="vegetables"/></xsl:template>

Comment: Can you explain the requirement using the input XML data? It is not possible to make out from the result that you have posted.